# loop through an array one time to populate an iFrame then go to another page when loop is finished

Tags: javascript

I am new to Javascript and I am lost on how to loop through an array of html documents to populate an iFrame one at a time using a click next button. Here is what I have been struggling with

```
window.onload = loadPages;

function loadPages () {
        var frameThem = document.getElementById("frameWrap");
        var arr = ["aCard.html", "bCard.html", "cCard.html", "dCard.html"];

        for (index = 0;index < arr.length; index++) {

            frameThem.src = (arr[index]);
        }

};

document.getElementById('nextButton').onclick = loadPages();
```

This only loads the last html document. I appreciate any help I can get. Thanks.

Comment: here you need to create an array of frames so that you may be able to see all of them at the same time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will  show them one by one, showing the next one when you click the button.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<button id="nextButton">NEXT!</button>
<iframe id="frame1"></iframe>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var lastloaded = 0;
    window.onload = loadPages;

    function loadPages () {
        var frame = document.getElementById("frame1");
        var arr = ["aCard.html", "bCard.html", "cCard.html", "dCard.html"];
        if (lastloaded+1>arr.length){
            lastloaded = 0;
        }
        frame.src = arr[lastloaded];
        lastloaded++;
        }
        document.getElementById('nextButton').onclick = loadPages;
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var index = 0;
var arr = ["aCard.html", "bCard.html", "cCard.html", "dCard.html"];

function loadPages () {
    document.getElementById("frameWrap").src = (arr[index]);
    index = (index + 1) % arr.length;
};

window.onload = loadPages;
document.getElementById('nextButton').onclick = loadPages();
```